# Cross-checking one MySQL table of text content against another table of keywords

Tags: mysql, join, keyword, tagging

Let's say I have two tables:

Table 1 has the columns NOTE_ID (a unique key) and NOTE_BODY (a big text blurb).

Table 2 has the columns KEYWORD_ID (a unique key) and KEYWORD (a keyword).

I want to get a result set that tells me which keywords each NOTE_BODY contains, without nesting a bunch of loops.  So ideally I would get a row for each NOTE_BODY-KEYWORD match.

What's the right way to go about this?  I'm unsure if a JOIN+LIKE'%%' does the trick, or if I should be using full-text indexing.  Any help much appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full text indexing solution is the right way to do this, if you plan to have many rows. You could use [MySQL's native solution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) if you are using the [MyISAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myisam) storage engine, but you could also consider the popular third-party search engines [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) and [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/).

On the other hand, a simple `INNER JOIN` would have done the trick:

```
SELECT  t1.note_id, t1.note_body, t2.keyword
FROM    table_1 t1
JOIN    table_2 t2 ON (t1.note_body LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.keyword, '%'));
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (note_id int, note_body varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE table_2 (keyword_id int, keyword varchar(50));

INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES (1, 'Hello Stack Overflow');
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES (2, 'Hello World');
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES (3, 'Hello, my name is Daniel');
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES (4, 'Goodbye');

INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES (1, 'Hello');
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES (2, 'name');
```

Result:

```
+---------+--------------------------+---------+
| note_id | note_body                | keyword |
+---------+--------------------------+---------+
|       1 | Hello Stack Overflow     | Hello   |
|       2 | Hello World              | Hello   |
|       3 | Hello, my name is Daniel | Hello   |
|       3 | Hello, my name is Daniel | name    |
+---------+--------------------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I'll go for the indexing option, but also good to know that the join will take care of it if the dataset involved is small enough (after many attempts I still can't keep my JOINs straight...).